# How to override findAll method of Mongo Repository

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to override the `findAll(Pageable pageable)` method of the mongo repository, however can't quite do it.

I have created a repository called `MyRestRepository` that looks like this:

```
public interface MyRestRepository extends MongoRepository<Notify, String>, MyRestRepositoryCustom {
   ...
}
```

Inside the `MyRestRepositoryCustom` interface I have added this code:

```
@Modifying
Page<Notify> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

And finally I have the implementation of `MyRestRepositoryCustom`:

```
public class MyRestRepositoryImpl implements MyRestRepositoryCustom {
 @Override
 public Page<Notify> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
      // This doesn't work
      Page<Notify> results = super.findAll(pageable);
      // Do other stuff here to results...
      return results;

}
```

I want to call the findAll method on the original repository so that I can get the contents of the page and then modify it. However, this doesn't work. How can I do this??

Comment: Do you want to overwrite it for one Repository or for all Repositories in the application?

Comment: For one specific repository. Could you provide some code with your answer?

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

`MyRestRepositoryImpl` has to extend `SimpleMongoRepository`. You don't have to define `findAll` in the interface.

```
public class MyRestRepositoryImpl extends SimpleMongoRepository implements MyRestRepositoryCustom {
 //call the super instructor
 public   MyRestRepositoryImpl(....) {
       super(....);
 }

 @Override
 public Page<Notify> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
      // This doesn't work
      Page<Notify> results = super.findAll(pageable);
      // Do other stuff here to results...
      return results;

}
}
```

Comment: And what is on line 24?

Comment: Sorry, it's the `public class MyRestRepository..` line. I've tried moving the extends before the implements, and that seems to do something but that messes up other stuff. There needs to be some generics I think. Sorry for asking a lot of questions, I'm not a native Java developer!

Comment: Yes, extends should be before implements. I was typing in a hurry. I changed that.  You also need to specify types for generics.